# Unable to cross compile Linux openGL program with mingw32. Config.log error: undefined reference to `_glEnable'

Tags: c++, opengl, cross-compiling, fedora, mingw32

I am attempting to cross-compile an OpenGL program using Mingw32 but have run into a road block.  After invoking mingw32-configure; the compilation is interrupted by

```
configure: error: lacking proper OpenGL support
```

I checked the config.log file and found the following entries:

```
configure:21709: checking GL/gl.h usability  
configure:21726: ccache i686-pc-mingw32-g++ -c -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -mms-bitfields      conftest.cpp >&5  
configure:21732: $? = 0  
configure:21746: result: yes  
configure:21750: checking GL/gl.h presence  
configure:21765: ccache i686-pc-mingw32-g++ -E  conftest.cpp  
configure:21771: $? = 0  
configure:21785: result: yes  
configure:21813: checking for GL/gl.h  
configure:21820: result: yes  
configure:21834: checking for glEnable in -lGL  
configure:21869: ccache i686-pc-mingw32-g++ -o conftest.exe -O2 -g -pipe -    Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -mms-      bitfields   conftest.cpp -lGL   >&5
/tmp/ccjGmlvX.o: In function 'main':../rpmbuild/SOURCES/poker3d-1.1.36/conftest.cpp:34: undefined reference to `_glEnable'  
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status  
configure:21875: $? = 1  
configure: failed program was:  
| /* confdefs.h.  */
```

I have added the llvm software rasterizer to my system after a suggestion on this website from another thread related to this problem and have also implemented a suggestion from the Mingw site to copy libopengl32.a to libGL.a.  So far nothing has changed the errors that I get after each compile attempt.

Give me some advice on how to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

autotools/autoconf is abysmally bad for crosscompilation. The way the generated `configure` script works is, that for many tests it attempts to compile **and execute** short test snippet programs. Of course the whole "execute" part will miserably fail for cross compiled libraries, due to either lack in instruction set support (compiling for a different CPU) or targeting an entirely different OS.

At least in Linux one can work around this using the "misc binfmt" kernel support, which allows to register interpreters for non-native executable formats. For Windows targets you'd use *Wine* as an interpreter and for foreign CPUs you can use QEmu which not only can emulate whole machines, but focus CPU emulation on a single process/binary. And of course you can combine it.

However this is just a crutch and honestly you should probably ditch autoconf/autotools entirely and just write Makefiles. Today the *nix-ish systems are so similar that none of these compiled tests make a lot of sense at all.